# Не запускается программа написанная с применением PyQt5

Tags: python, pyqt5, pycharm

После переустановки системы перестала запускаться программа написанная на Python + PyQt5.

При попытке запуска в PyCharm, появляется окно

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код файла main:

```
"""# -- coding: utf-8 --"""

import sys

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget, QMainWindow

from zvk_gui import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QCalendarWidget


class MyWindow(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        date = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate()
        day_of_week = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().dayOfWeek()
        print(day_of_week)
        format_date = 'dd MMMM yyyy'
        if day_of_week == 1:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(
                date.addDays(7).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(6).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(5).toString(format_date)
                )
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 2:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 3:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 4:
            self.label.setText(
                date.addDays(9).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(10).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(11).toString(format_date)
            )
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(
                date.addDays(2).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(3).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(4).toString(format_date)
            )
        else:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(
                date.addDays(8).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(9).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(10).toString(format_date)
            )
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        self.calendarWidget.clicked['QDate'].connect(self.show_date_func)


    def show_date_func(self, date):
        format_date = 'dd MMMM yyyy'
        day_of_week = self.calendarWidget.selectedDate().dayOfWeek()
        print(day_of_week)
        if day_of_week == 1:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(
                date.addDays(7).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(6).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(5).toString(format_date)
            )
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 2:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 3:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))
        elif day_of_week == 4:
            self.label.setText(
                date.addDays(9).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(10).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(11).toString(format_date)
            )
            self.label_6.setText(date.addDays(8).toString(format_date))
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(
                date.addDays(2).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(3).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(4).toString(format_date)
            )
        else:
            self.label.setText(date.addDays(9).toString(format_date))
            self.label_6.setText(
                date.addDays(8).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(9).toString(format_date) + '\n' +
                date.addDays(10).toString(format_date)
            )
            self.label_7.setText(date.addDays(7).toString(format_date))
            self.label_8.setText(date.addDays(2).toString(format_date))


    if __name__ == "__main__":
        app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
        application = MyWindow()
        application.show()
        sys.exit(app.exec())
```

На ноутбуке, где все по старому все запускается.
Поискал таблетку в интернете. Прочитал, что надо папку ***platforms*** создать в папке с программой и туда скопировать файл ***qwindows.dll*** - не помогло. Что еще можно сделать?

Comment: а если запустить вашу программу через терминал/CMD, что вы получаете ?

Comment: Через cmd просто запускается pycharm и открывает указанный файл. Или я что-то не так делаю? Я просто вбиваю имя файла в папке где лежит программа....

Comment: а вы запускаете командой "python "имя файла.py""?

Comment: Да все заработало, когда запустил через cmd командой python. А с чем связана такая ошибка? Как ее пофиксить?

Comment: Причем сделал упаковку программы через pyinstaller и все работает...Создал новый проект, сделал в нем простенький виджет и все работает даже из PyCharm. Ясно что ошибка была допущена при переносе проекта на новую систему.... Осталось ее найти)

Answer (score 0):

Попробуйте запускать так:

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])
    ex = MyWindow()
    ex.show()
    app.exec_()
```

Comment: Проблема осталась

Comment: А почему self.setupUi(self) а не super().setupUi(self)?

Comment: скажите пожалуйста, чем лучше предложенный вами вариант чем записанный у автора вопроса?